# iPhone: Issue with UILocalNotification flow

Tags: iphone

My requirement is, my app to get notified for every 10 mins and do some process under the notification receive event even after i close my application, so as i created UILocalNotification code as below, just for testing purpose i set a notification sound there. After i close my application and come to device home screen, i get notification sound only once and doesn't come to "didReceiveLocalNotification" event in my program.
In general, notification shows as notify alert with some body and click on "View" button there, takes to our application "didReceiveLocalNotification" event method. But i don't want to show any notify alert, and my app should get called with "didReceiveLocalNotification" event method kind of as the background process. Please advise me how can i resolve my issue with UILocalNotification API? If my app should get notified every 10 mins in the background is not possible using UILocalNotification, then what else method can i try to resolve it?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [self initLocalNotification : 600];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

-(void) initLocalNotification :(int) seconds {

    // Notity after 10 * 60 seconds
    NSDate *notificationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:seconds];

    if ( notify )
        notify = NULL; 
    notify = [ [UILocalNotification alloc] init ];
    notify.fireDate = notificationDate;
    //notify.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    notify.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notify.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    //notify.alertBody = @"Local notification test";
    notify.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitDay;

    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"notifiValue" forKey:@"notifiKey"];
    notify.userInfo = infoDict;

    NSLog(@"Initiate notification in %d seconds", seconds);

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notify];
    [notify release];

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"Notification triggerred..");
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [ self initLocalNotification : 600 ];
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both local and push notifications won't trigger Application Delegate methods unless the user accepts the notification (i.e. taps View).

Note that applications marked as VOIP apps can do stuff in background periodically by using UIApplication setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:, and apps marked as using location services will receive location updates while in the background. However, you if you mark your app as VOIP or location-aware, you will have to justify that with Apple - i.e. you will have to actually provide a VOIP/Location service to the user in order for your app to be approved.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much! I think i can't go with UILLocalnotification if it needs to display alert must. If i want to use location services, how does it work? Can my app set some time interval and get notified at that time to do some tasks? Are there any tutorials or sample to go through?

Comment: With location services you'll get a notification when the location changes, so if the user stays in one place you won't get many notifications (especially if you only register for "significant location changes" only, which you should do to save battery). And the app will have to actually provide some location services to the user, otherwise it'll get rejected.

Comment: Oh ok! If location notification gets notified only when location changed on the phone then it will not be useful for my purpose! Then do not know how would i achieve my requirement for background notification(even when my app is closed) for every certain interval on iOS development?